# SWT FileDialog error: constructor FileDialog is undefined

Tags: java, swt, filedialog

I'm just starting with Java basic and having this issue with SWT `FileDialog`. Eclipse always returns this error: **The constructor `FileDialog(Shell, int)` is undefined**

Below is the full code, could you please help to advise?

```
public class FormObject2 {

protected Shell shell;
private Text txtComboBoxItem;
private final FormToolkit formToolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getDefault());
private Text taOne;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FormObject2 window = new FormObject2();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(481, 364);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenuBar(menu);

    MenuItem mntmFile = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmFile.setText("File");

    Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmFile);
    mntmFile.setMenu(menu_1);

    MenuItem mntmOpen = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmOpen.setAccelerator(1);
    mntmOpen.setText("Open");
    mntmOpen.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1+ 'O');

    MenuItem mntmSave = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmSave.setAccelerator(1);
    mntmSave.setText("Save");

    MenuItem mntmEdit = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmEdit.setText("Edit");

    Menu menu_2 = new Menu(mntmEdit);
    mntmEdit.setMenu(menu_2);

    MenuItem mntmExit = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmExit.setText("Exit");

    mntmOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
          public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
             FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.MULTI);
              dialog.setFilterPath("C:\\Logs");
              dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[]{"*.txt", "*.pdf", "*.*"});
              dialog.setFilterNames(new String[]{ "Rich Text Format", "HTML Document", "Any"});
              dialog.open();
          }
          });        
}
```

Comment: i hope this answer is usefull..thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are probably importing the wrong `FileDialog` class - you need to be importing `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog` **not** `java.awt.FileDialog`